# Set start date and restrict dates in datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to set start date to 14 days from today. Below 14 days date will not be selectable. I also need to lock the next 13 days as not selectable.

```js
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  keyboardNavigation: false,
  forceParse: false,
  startDate: new Date(),
  autoclose: true
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="productDate" id="productDate" class="form-control" maxlength="20" placeholder="Date" value="{{ date('m/d/Y',strtotime($productDate))}}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var newdate = new Date();
newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() - 14);
$('input').datepicker({
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  keyboardNavigation: false,
  forceParse: false,
  minDate: newdate,
  startDate: newdate,
  autoclose: true
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.5.4/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.5.4/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" name="productDate" id="productDate" class="form-control" maxlength="20" placeholder="Date" value="">
```